# Same app running multiple times

Tags: android

My app can run multiple times. I start it, press home, then click the app icon again, then i exit the app two times. How is this possible on android?

Comment: Huh? What's the question? Why do you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, look up android:launchMode on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), which states:

An activity with the "standard" or "singleTop" launch mode can be instantiated multiple times.
In contrast, "singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities can only begin a task. They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one such task.

Comment: Thank You very much. When I start to think I know a language it turns out, that I don't.